Macbook air boots directly to grub menu, can't access BIOS or Boot menu anymore
Running Macbook air 2017 with inuxmint 21.1 xfce, even if I press alt key or alt+e or command+alt+r while booting, it jumps directly to grub menu and i can't access BIOS or boot options. I can't even install any other distro.
"sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup" does not help, increasing grub timeout won't help as I want BIOS and not grub.
Thanks.

Macbooks are not PCs, and they don't have a PC-style BIOS at all.
A 2017 Macbook Air would be an Intel-based one. So the applicable boot-time keypresses are listed in this Apple Support article.
If you have set up a firmware password, some of these keypresses won't work. You can use macOS Recovery to turn off a firmware password, details here.

Command (⌘)-R: start built-in macOS Recovery.
Option-Command-R: Internet Recovery: download the most recent compatible macOS over the internet and install it.
Shift-Option-Command-R: download the macOS version that originally came with the Mac, or the closest version still available.
Option (⌥) or Alt: open Startup Manager, which allows you to boot from another disk or external media. (I guess this is what you're trying to do?)
Option-Command-P-R: reset NVRAM/PRAM.
Shift (⇧): start up in safe mode. (applies to macOS)
D: start Apple Diagnostics locally.
Option-D: start Apple Diagnostics over the internet.
N: attempt to start from a netboot server (should be supported in Macbook Air 2017 and newer).
T: start up in target disk mode.

Note that you should press and hold Option/Alt before you press the power key to power on the Macbook, and keep it held down until you see the Startup Manager or a firmware password prompt.

That seemed an hardware issue for the keyboard. As the keyboard wasn't working fine at times after booting inside Linux too, I gave Linux multiple boots to find keyboard working and not workIng randomly, so thought to try  boot-time keypresses multiple times and it worked. But I had tried multiple times earlier also but it didn't work earlier but now.
